# Can Terran Medivacs heal allied units?

Tags: starcraft-2

Can Terran Medivacs heal allied units? Can they heal Zerg units or Protoss units aside from themselves?

Comment: Why the down votes? This is a reasonable question. Easy to figure out, but still a good question.

Comment: @ayckoster It is easy to figure out and self-answered. That is just noise on the site since I doubt this is a real problem the user faced.

Comment: @Resorath This information isn't prominently featured on the wiki sites, so it's actually nice to have it asked and answered concisely on Arqade. Although the answer may seem obvious to many experienced BW and SC2 players, it's actually not explained to new players and not trivial to test. Nevertheless, I expect high quality answers because it's a straightforward question. For example, not just "Yes, I've always done this," but "Here's a couple screenshots or a video of a medivac healing various allied units of a different race."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Terran Medivacs can heal any allied biological units.
The restrictions to Medivac's Heal ability are:

- Must be Biological.
- Must not be a structure.  (Queen's transfuse skips this restriction)
- Must not be an enemy unit. (You can get around this with Neural Parasite)

[image: Starcraft 2 Help Biological]

Additionally you can repair allied mechanical units(/structures) with SCV's or mules.
I.E. Collosi, Carriers, Stalkers etc.  (Protoss structures are not mechanical :( )

Comment: As a matter of fact, there's an achievement for healing 300 hp of allied units in a league game. (Neighborly Help)

Comment: Neural parasite enemy unit, then your own team's medivacs heal it up... talk about a plan backfiring

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Terran Medivacs can heal all types of biological units. This includes all Zerg Units and Zealots from the Protoss army.

Comment: Haha why are you answering your own question 1 minute after you asked it :P

Comment: @BenLefebvre Good question. Normally it's acceptable form to answer a question you had yourself after some independent research if no one else figured it out before you did, but that isn't what looks like occurred here.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question (Q&A style), in fact there is even a checkbox below the question form if you want to do it. It's for when you found out something awesome and want to document it here. However, this question seems like a pretty simple one. Not sure if it was necessary to document it. (If you didn't know the answer and were honestly asking, that would be different.)

Comment: Can you cite a source, or better yet, post screenshots, or better yet, post a video?

Comment: Queens can heal zerg buildings as they are bio, can medivacs heal Zerg buildings too? I've never seen it happen, but haven't tried either. Thinking that a medivac/spine crawler wall might be pretty hard to break!

Comment: You should add that they can only heal Protoss bio units hit points, not their shields. And they cannot heal flying units, like Mutas and Broodlords.

Comment: They can heal mutas & broodlords actually... broodlord medivac is an extremely powerful combo in 2v2

Comment: I would add them to my answer, but someone beat me to it :)